# What are the advantages and disadvantages of metaprogramming?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

As the title stated, what are the pros and cons of Ruby meta-programming?

So far I know the advantages of Ruby meta-programming give us quite flexible ways to write our code using code that writes code. But what are the disadvantages? Maintainability issues?

I feel that meta-programming helps to scale an app also.

Can anyone can give more details about this?

Answer (score 3):

Almost everything I know about metaprogramming in Ruby comes from "[Metaprogramming Ruby: Program Like the Ruby Pros](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby)". It's a great read, and I suggest it to everyone who want to understand metaprogramming.

I'd say the main advantage is to have incredibly flexible code, which can adapt swiftly to any changes one could imagine. Things like `send`, `respond_to?` or `define_method` really give you the possibility of writing beautiful code.

On the other hand, I'd say that the main disadvantage is to make code harder to read and harder to debug, since most of the times the code *isn't there* yet! It will be generated at runtime, so you can't actually read it when you debug it.

Comment: how about the scalability and maintainability?